# who has the right to access to a smart contrat's storage space?

Tags: storage

Contracts have 2 ** 256 32-byte storage slots available to store data in. This can be thought of as each contract having it's own database.
Can all nodes in a blockchain network access to smart contract's storage space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any node in the network can read this data but only your smart contract can add/update/delete it.

This method can be used to read the storage of a contract https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat

Answer (score 0):

No.

Only you smart contract is able to alter this storage!

The functions you have in your contract define the conditions under which this storage can be changed.

Comment: thank you for your reply but i meant "to read" the storage of the smart contract not to alter this storage